# how to fit this simple mnist clasification

Tags: keras

this keras is a simple keras model, I use relu for simplicity and power of learning
also mean_square as a loss, but the model does not fit
I spect the output to be a number [0-9], im not using to_categorical, thas why there is only a output neuron

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
(data, labels),(x_test,y_test) = mnist.load_data()

from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Flatten
from keras.models import Model
from keras.losses import mean_squared_error

# This returns a tensor
inputs = Input(shape=(28, 28,))
x = Flatten()(inputs)

x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(1, activation='relu')(x)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss=mean_squared_error,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(data, labels, batch_size=10, epochs=10 ,
              validation_data=(x_test, y_test))  # starts training
```

Comment: This is not how you do classification, it is well known not to work, there is a reason why we use one neuron per output class.